# SSRS expression IIF with aggregate function in if true part

Tags: reporting-services, expression, aggregate-functions, iif

This SSRS expression gets me what I need:

`=CountDistinct(IIF(Fields!BuildingNumber.Value = "1" AND Fields!InspectionCycle.Value ="A" OR Fields!InspectionCycle.Value ="B" ,Fields!ParcelID.Value,Nothing), "DataSet1")
-CountDistinct(IIF(Fields!BuildingNumber.Value = "1" AND Fields!InspectionCycle.Value ="A" ,Fields!ParcelID.Value,Nothing), "DataSet1")`
I wish to add this condition to the start of it:
`=IIF(Parameters!Cycle.Value(0)="A"`
And I assume I need to add something like this to the end:
`,Nothing), "DataSet1")`
I would like to then continue with:
`OR =IIF(Parameters!Cycle.Value(0)="B"`

### I am getting a ')' expected error. Also, is the (0)necessary in the condition? Thank you for your time!

Based on your help here is a working expression:

`=IIF(INSTR(JOIN(Parameters!Cycle.Value, ","), "B") > 0, CountDistinct(IIF(Fields!BuildingNumber.Value = "1" AND Fields!InspectionCycle.Value ="B" OR Fields!InspectionCycle.Value ="A" ,Fields!ParcelID.Value,0), "NRBuildingsInsp")-CountDistinct(IIF(Fields!BuildingNumber.Value = "1" AND Fields!InspectionCycle.Value ="A" ,Fields!ParcelID.Value,0), "NRBuildingsInsp"),0)`
And here it checks another parameter if the first is false:

### `=IIF(INSTR(JOIN(Parameters!Cycle.Value, ","), "B") > 0, CountDistinct(IIF(Fields!BuildingNumber.Value = "1" AND Fields!InspectionCycle.Value ="B" OR Fields!InspectionCycle.Value ="A" ,Fields!ParcelID.Value,0), "NRBuildingsInsp")-CountDistinct(IIF(Fields!BuildingNumber.Value = "1" AND Fields!InspectionCycle.Value ="A" ,Fields!ParcelID.Value,0), "NRBuildingsInsp"),IIF(INSTR(JOIN(Parameters!Cycle.Value, ","), "C") > 0, CountDistinct(IIF(Fields!BuildingNumber.Value = "1" AND Fields!InspectionCycle.Value ="C" OR Fields!InspectionCycle.Value ="A" ,Fields!ParcelID.Value,0), "NRBuildingsInsp")-CountDistinct(IIF(Fields!BuildingNumber.Value = "1" AND Fields!InspectionCycle.Value ="A" ,Fields!ParcelID.Value,0), "NRBuildingsInsp"))`

How would I have to modify it to provide results where Parameters!Cycle.Value = both "B" and "C"?

Comment: Can you show your updated expression? Why do you need the `, "DataSet1")` at the end. I think that's your problem. That goes with the `CountDistinct` function, not the `IIF` you added.

Comment: Is your CYCLE parameter multi-value? The `(0)` is the indicator of the first selected parameter in a multi-value. To check for a value in any multi-value selection, you could use `=IIF(INSTR(JOIN(Parameters!Cycle.Value, ","), "B") > 0, <TRUE_PART>, <FALSE_PART>)`. This will combine a multi-value parameter's selected values into a string and check for a `B` - returning 0 if not found or the character position if found.

Comment: =IIF(INSTR(JOIN(Parameters!... worked!! Thank you so much. I love learning something new.

Comment: I don't know why some of the text above switched to bold?? How would I have to modify the expression to provide results where Parameters!Cycle.Value = both "B" and "C"?

Comment: Just add an OR and add another INTR comparison with the B - =IIF(INSTR(JOIN(Parameters!Cycle.Value, ","), "B") > 0 OR INSTR(JOIN(Parameters!Cycle.Value, ","), "C") > 0, <TRUE_PART>, <FALSE_PART>)